# Google Place API Missing Opening Hours

Tags: json, google-maps, google-places-api, missing-data, google-places

I am implementing a Google Place service on my end. When I retrieved the json object, I realized that there are missing arrays in the json object (opening_hours). Below is an example of the object retrieved. Does anyone know why certain fields are missing?

```
Hi, i referred to your answers and find a place which has opening hours in google maps but still does not exist in the json object. Below is the example.

[{
  "html_attributions": \[
    "Listings by <a href=\"http://www.openrice.com/\">OpenRice</a>"
  \],
  "results": \[
    {
      "formatted_address": "30 Raffles Ave, Singapore 039803",
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 1.2892988,
          "lng": 103.8631368
        }
      },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id": "021245e36680793a72b3c428607f0a01ed5d1786",
      "name": "Singapore Flyer",
      "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": true,
        "weekday_text": \[\]
      },
      "photos": \[
        {
          "height": 2048,
          "html_attributions": \[
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115338279981022433314/photos\">David Montasco</a>"
          \],
          "photo_reference": "CmRdAAAAWbq-OmrKkZ0Rz9JyDVrnnMjD760XaCdEPBOYLITUhfUCcr6N4YmsMUxyou5yWnMQs4_iQhQc04cR4WOrDuqR5a43ZaH5O5zv4O783lXZP4qDosm-bnUUmyCOV7pNH76LEhBgl4L5ScAvva4b4TkM7-UGGhTmUVujviiDHGICoITSZr5JKJFgQA",
          "width": 1367
        }
      \],
      "place_id": "ChIJzVHFNqkZ2jERboLN2YrltH8",
      "rating": 4.3,
      "reference": "CnRiAAAACBop0imOgmYxPrAp_4b6CIgkGMeaaWb6oL-RsoOK6CxElf7-yNPBz_q5qXVpTfVpsmtWDua6r7gEZdsi9420icrp-mnpG6HLiGmmHupluWkUmuRCdwQ8BRlPW_HYAP9qEblbZMoAbvBDGMZgk_QyoRIQtPeJRN6-_Nm66jH-OMsCBBoUkZDaSDMQqEyPpCOyysU6ulgZtA8",
      "types": \[
        "establishment"
      \]
    }
  \],
  "status": "OK"
}][1]
```

Comment: I would verify what you grabbing from google and make sure that it is not nested inside the object. Hope this helps.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) says the result **may** contain the following fields (which include opening_hours. Why do you expect it to be there?

Comment: Can you add the request that is getting this data? I believe only registered businesses with Google will have the opening_hours data. I.e. if I search for my house it will not have opening_hours, but if I search for my nearby bank, it will. Are you searching for a Google-registered business?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Places documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places):

> Places that do not specify opening hours in the Google Places database will not be returned.

This means that a place has to register their opening hours with Google before this parameter gets returned. I see that you are searching for the Place de la Concorde in Paris. When I do a normal Google search for them, their hours do not show up in the sidebar Google Address widget. This means that they have not registered their opening hours with Google and therefore that data will be excluded from any Google Places request. You should get that data back if you request a place that has registered that information with Google.

Comment: The part of the documentation you refer to is saying "**if** you use the _open now_ filter in your search, **then** places without opening hours will be excluded."  But this question is about a result that **is** returned, just that it doesn't have an `opening_hours` field (so pretty much by definition the request that produced this result was not using that filter!).  The rest of your answer seems right to me, but you're referring to an irrelevant part of the documentation.

Comment: I chose that line from the documentation because it shows that your opening hours *must be specified within the Google database* and that means that the `opening_hours` parameter will be optional. But you're right - the specific area that I took that line from does not refer to the `opening_hours` field directly. If you find a better place in the documentation that specifies the bit about the database *and* is this exact field, then please edit my answer with that quote instead. However, I think we both agree that regardless of the quote source location, this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't have opening hours for this place, so it's expected that there is no `opening_hours` field for it in the Google Places API.  If you look at this place on Google Maps you won't see opening hours shown there either: https://maps.google.com/?cid=1730241942096554796

The [comment from geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347257/google-place-api-missing-opening-hours#comment58401839_35347257) is right:

> [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) says the result **may** contain the following fields (which include opening_hours

Similarly, many other fields like `rating` or `price_level` can be (and often are) absent.